# How to implement onActivityResult outside the activity class

Tags: android, google-play-services, onactivityresult

I implemented a ManageGoogleService class to manage my game's achievements and leaderboards.

The mechanism of unlock and show achievements, and submit and show leaderboards work fine.
But I'm having problems when I try to disconnect to google, or when i click on disconnect button in the leaderboards setting (Not signed in when calling API error).

I can't able to reconnect to google service.
I think the problem is the onActivityResult method.
How I can implement this method in my ManageGoogleService class and not in the activity class?
It's possible that there is no way to do this? (As I read on the Internet.)

This is my MainActivity that I use to test my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ManageGoogleServices manageGoogleServices;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in);
    //  Button signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sign_out);
    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    manageGoogleServices = new ManageGoogleServices(this,this, mainView);

    //  signIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    //   signOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button_sign_out).setOnClickListener(this);

    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    four.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/* protected void onResume(){
      int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
      if( result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
          Log.d("MYTAG", "SUCCESS");
          GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(result);
      }else{
          if( result == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING){
              Log.d("MYTAG", "service missing");
          }
          if( result == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED){
              Log.d("MYTAG", "Service version update required");
          }
          if( result == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED){
              Log.d("MYTAG", "Service disabled");
          }
          if( result == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID){
              Log.d("MYTAG", "Service invalid");
          }

      }
  }*/


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


// Shows the "sign in" bar (explanation and button).
private void showSignInBar() {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Showing sign in bar");
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

// Shows the "sign out" bar (explanation and button).
private void showSignOutBar() {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Showing sign out bar");
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button_sign_in:

             Log.d("MYTAG", "Sign-in button clicked");
            manageGoogleServices.connectToGoogleService();
            showSignOutBar();
            break;

        case R.id.button_sign_out:

            // sign out.
            Log.d("MYTAG", "Sign-out button clicked");
            manageGoogleServices.disconnectToGoogleService();
            showSignInBar();
            break;

        // unlock the achievement
        case R.id.one:

            manageGoogleServices.unlockAchievements(getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_achievement_57));

            break;

        //show the achivements list
        case R.id.two:

            manageGoogleServices.showAchievementsList();

            break;

        // submitScore in leaderboards
        case R.id.three:

            manageGoogleServices.addScoreToLeaderboard(1,"text",1);

            break;

        //see the leaderboards
        case R.id.four:

           manageGoogleServices.showLeaderboards(1,"text");
           break;
    }
}
```

This is a sample layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" style="@style/MainLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- MAIN DISPLAY -->
<FrameLayout style="@style/MainDisplay">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/one" android:text="@string/click_me"
            style="@style/Button" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/two" android:text="showachievements"
            style="@style/Button" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/three" android:text="updlb"
            style="@style/Button" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/four" android:text="showleaderboards"
            style="@style/Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- SIGN-IN BAR -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sign_in_bar" style="@style/SignInOutBar">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/button_sign_in" style="@style/SignInButton" />

    <TextView style="@style/SignInOutBarBlurb" android:text="@string/sign_in_explanation" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- SIGN-OUT BAR -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sign_out_bar" style="@style/SignInOutBar"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView style="@style/SignInOutBarBlurb"
        android:text="@string/you_are_signed_in" />

    <Button style="@style/SignOutButton" android:id="@+id/button_sign_out"
        android:text="@string/sign_out" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my ManageGoogleServices class:

```
    public class ManageGoogleServices implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    Context context;
    Activity activityName;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    int REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS = 1;
    int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 1;

    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;

    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

    // Set to true to automatically start the sign in flow when the Activity starts.
    // Set to false to require the user to click the button in order to sign in.
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;

    public ManageGoogleServices(Context context, Activity activityName, View viewForPopups){

        this.context = context;
        this.activityName = activityName;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .setViewForPopups(viewForPopups)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)

                .build();

        connectToGoogleService();
    }


    public void connectToGoogleService(){

        try {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {

             /*   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                        .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                        .build();
            */

                mSignInClicked = true;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                Log.d("MYTAG", " GOOGLE API CLIENT CONNECTED");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnectToGoogleService(){

        mSignInClicked = false;

        try {

            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

                Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d("MYTAG", "DISCONNESSO CORRETTAMENTE");
                }

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void unlockAchievements(String achievementsId ){

        connectToGoogleService();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            // unlock the  achievement.

            Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, achievementsId);

          /*  Games.Achievements.unlockImmediate(mGoogleApiClient, achievementsId).setResultCallback(
                    new  ResultCallback<Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult result) {

                            System.out.println(result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                        }
                    });
            */

        }else{
            Log.d("MYTAG", "NOT CONNECTED");
        }
    }

    public void showAchievementsList(){

        connectToGoogleService();

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

            activityName.startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);

        }else{
            Log.d("MYTAG", "NOT CONNECTED");
        }
    }

    // Update the score to leaderboard
    public void addScoreToLeaderboard(int gameID , String difficultyLevel, int myScore){

        connectToGoogleService();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

            switch (gameID) {

                ...

            }

        }else{

            Log.d("MYTAG", "NOT CONNECTED");
        }
    }


    public void showLeaderboards(int gameID , String difficultyLevel){

        connectToGoogleService();

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

            switch (gameID) {

                ...
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("MYTAG", "NOT CONNECTED");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        Log.d("MYTAG", "onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
        connectToGoogleService();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            // Already resolving
            return;
        }

        // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
        // launch the sign-in flow
        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
            // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
            // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
            // an issue with sign in, please try again later."
            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(activityName,
                    mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, "sign in!!!!!")) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Log.d("MYTAG", "onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode="
                    + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (responseCode == activityName.RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(activityName, requestCode, responseCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to do that, as after all it's the activity that calls the startActivityForResult method, and not the wrapper class (ManageGoogleServices), even though the calling is there.

You'll have to handle the result in the activity's onActivityResult method and from there to pass the result to the wrapper class:

manageGoogleServices.onResult("data....")

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Update**

Yes, it’s possible if your project uses [Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10).

If you have the Activity instance and its type is AppCompatActivity, you will have the activity.registerForActivityResult(), like this:

```kotlin
(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.apply {
//-------------------------------------------------------<InputType, OutputType>
    registerForActivityResult(object : ActivityResultContract<Unit, String?>() {
        override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent =
            Intent(YOUTCLASS:class.java).apply {
            // Put your extras here
            }

        override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) =
           // GetYour extras here
           intent?.getStringExtra(ShortcutsNotLoggedActivity.REDIRECT_OPKEY)

    }) { resultStringInThisCase ->
        // Do whatever you want with the result
    }.launch(null) // Pass your input if you have one
}
```

This way, you can register the result for any activity outside it.

More information and Java version on Android Developer documentation: *[Get a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin)*

Comment: The `developer.android.com` link is half-broken (page anchor).